# Compute number of days with snow

Tags: arcgis-desktop, grass-gis, modis

I have a project and I want to map the effective number of days with snow cover for a year in some mountain area. Until now, I have processed the MOD10A2 (8 days snow cover) product derived from MODIS and I want to count the occurrence of 200 pixel value (this value correspond to the snow extent). I have tried to aggregate raster into the temporal gis offered by GRASS but the results are unsatisfactory. Any ideas?  I can handle ArcInfo, GRASS GIS and R pretty well.

Thanks!

Comment: You could reclass the 8 day product to a binary product with 200 = 1 and all other values being zero. Then use the raster calculator to sum all of the reclassed 8 day products into a single raster layer.  Multiply this raster by 8 and you have number of days of snow cover. It has been a while since I have used these products. Isn't there a daily snow cover product, that is binary, representing 10% snow cover in each pixel? Whereas the 8 day has a value even if only one day during the 8 day period the pixel contained snow?

Comment: Yes it is, but the cloud cover in the winter months is often over 70-80%. Your solution seems to be promising.

Comment: Isn't it simply the count method of r.series? See http://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/r.series.html#examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in ArcGIS you can use [equal to frequency](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Equal_To_Frequency/009z0000007s000000/) for that. You can compute the number of times that the value of your stack of raster is equal to 200. It is recommended to create your stack in a vrt file (gdalbuildvrt) in order to avoid a huge files.

As a remark, we did a similar work, you can visualize the products [here](http://uclouvain.be/lifewatch) and they are freely available on request. Because of the amount of data, we used [OTB](http://orfeo-toolbox.org/otb/) for the processing. If you also need to process a large area, this could help.

Comment: It helps a lot.